X metrizable iff homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $[0,1]^{w}$
I am studying for an exam and in a recommended exercise I have to show the following equivalence:
$X$ is a compact Hausdorff space with a countable basis iff $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $[0,1]^{w}$.
I don't know how to solve this. I already know that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space with a countable basis means that $X$ is metrizable. Nevertheless, I don't know how to build the homeomorphism needed.
Thank you so much for helping me.

Urysohn's metrization theorem

@EvangelopoulosFoivos I already checked it and I found the right side (X compact Hausdorff 2 countable is homeomorphic to a subspace...). I haven´t been able to solve the other side. Any hints?

Seeing the comments and reading that you have already checked the right implication, and reading that you haven't been able to solve the other side, I'm gonna give you hints for the left implication.
Suppose that $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace $S$ of $[0, 1]^{\omega}$ (the Hilbert cube).
Hints:
$[0, 1]^{\omega}$ is a second countable compact metric space (for a reference, see space #$38$ in Counterexamples in Topology).
Metrizability and second countability are hereditary.
Every metrizable space is $T_2$.
Every closed subspace of a compact space is compact.
